# libtool picks up 64-bit library when I tries to build 32-bit program

Tags: 32-bit, autoconf, automake, libtool

I have a GNU build system with autoconf-2.69, automake-1.14.1, libtool-2.4.2. I've configured with --host=i686-linux on a x86_64 RHEL6 host OS to build a 32-bit program. The libtool command seems to be:

```
/bin/sh ../libtool  --tag=CXX   --mode=link g++ -I/home/STools/RLX/boost/include/boost-1_44  -m32 -g3 -Wall -static  -o engine engine-main.o ../components/librlxvm.la /home/STools/RLX/boost/include/boost-1_44/../../lib/libboost_program_options-gcc42-mt-1_44.a  -lz -lpthread -ldl  -lrt -ldl -lz -lm
```

But the real command is to search the 64-bit libraries not the 32-bit libraries as shown below:

```
libtool: link: g++ -I/home/STools/RLX/boost/include/boost-1_44 -m32 -g3 -Wall -o engine engine-main.o  -L/home/robert_bu/src/gcc/gcc-4.2.2/build-x86_64/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/src -L/home/robert_bu/src/gcc/gcc-4.2.2/build-x86_64/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/src/.libs -L/home/robert_bu/src/gcc/gcc-4.2.2/build-x86_64/./gcc ../components/.libs/librlxvm.a /home/STools/RLX/boost/include/boost-1_44/../../lib/libboost_program_options-gcc42-mt-1_44.a /home/STools/RLX/gcc-4.2.2-x86_64/lib/../lib64/libstdc++.so -L/lib/../lib64 -L/usr/lib/../lib64 -lc -lgcc_s -lrt -ldl -lz -lm -pthread -Wl,-rpath -Wl,/home/STools/RLX/gcc-4.2.2-x86_64/lib/../lib64 -Wl,-rpath -Wl,/home/STools/RLX/gcc-4.2.2-x86_64/lib/../lib64
```

The --host config seems to have no effect. Is there anyway to tell libtool that 32-bit libraries are what we want?

Comment: Usually you have to set at least `--build` and `--host` when croscompiling or `configure` will display a warning.  `--build=x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu --host=i686-redhat-linux-gnu` might fix it.

Comment: Tried your method, there's no difference.

Comment: It seems that libtool uses "CC", "CXX" to check the library search path. After I set CC to "gcc -m32", and CXX to "g++ -m32", it works. So libtool does not add "-m32" automatically even if I try to build a 32-bit program on a 64-bit system.

Comment: @Yorkwar stumbled upon this old question.  Just wanted to say that you proably should convert your last comment into an answer and select it, so that anyone it would help to know how you fixed the problem can easily find the solution.  Sadly it isn't the solution to my particular problem :)

Comment: @dsollen Got it:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that libtool uses "CC", "CXX" to check the library search path. After I set CC to "gcc -m32", and CXX to "g++ -m32", it works. So libtool does not add "-m32" automatically even if I try to build a 32-bit program on a 64-bit system.

Answer (score 0):

You're being hit by the problem of [libtool `.la` files expansion](https://blog.flameeyes.eu/tag/lafiles). In particular `libstdc++.la` is being expanded for you to a full path rather than a simple `-lstdc++`.

My suggestion is to remove `.la` file from the SDK you're using (`/home/STools`). This way `libtool` can't assume things for you. Usually the ones you have in the system are fine, because the libraries are already in the search path, so it does not need to use `-rpath` or the full path to the `.so` file.

Depending on how well the SDK was crafted, this might or might not work correctly, so take it with a grain of salt.